# Linear combination of i.i.d random variables

Tags: probability, measure-theory, statistics, random-variables

We say that a random variable $X$ satisfies the $(\alpha,\beta)-$condition for some $\alpha>0$ and $\beta>0$ if
$$\mathbb{P}(|X|<t)<\alpha t\text{ and }\mathbb{P}(|X|>t)<e^{-\beta t}\quad\forall t>0$$

Assume $X_1,\dots,X_m$ are i.i.d random variables satisfying the $(\alpha,\beta)-$condition for some $\alpha>0$ and $\beta>0$. Let $X=(X_1,\dots,X_m)$ and $x_0\in\mathbb{R}^m$ with $\Vert x_0\Vert_2=1$. Consider the random variable $Y=\langle X,x_0\rangle$. I am interested whether $Y$ satisfies the $(\alpha',\beta')-$condition for some $\alpha'>0$ and $\beta'>0$, i.e. 
$$\mathbb{P}(|Y|<t)<\alpha' t\text{ and }\mathbb{P}(|Y|>t)<e^{-\beta' t}\quad\forall t>0$$

Intuitively I felt the answer should be positive, but I am having difficulty to prove (or disprove) the statement. Any help is appreciated.